# How can I solve the problem “Ubuntu 20.04 pyenv command not found”?

Tags: 20.04, python, virtualenv

I am installing pyenv using this command:

```
git clone pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

Then

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

When I give this command, an error appears

```
$ source ~/.bashrc

Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:

  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5)
  command 'pyvenv' from deb python3-venv (3.8.2-0ubuntu2)
```

**My commands are as follow:**

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo −e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc

sudo apt-get install libc6-dev gcc

sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev wget curl llvm

git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
```

Comment: That apparently does not install pyenv, it installs the plugin pyenv-virtualenv. It requires pyenv to already be installed. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: @Kulfy I could not find a tag of 20.04 so that is why I mentioned 1404. I am using 20.04